# MySQL Group by Order By Struggling

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I know this question has been beaten to death and I've researched thoroughly, but none of the solutions suggested seem to work!

I'm trying to group by a field, and order by another Date field. So,here's what I have to start:

```
select cm.CreatedDate, cm.Id, cm.CampaignId, cm.ContactId 
from campaignmember as cm 
where cm.ContactId = '0035000002MYN7IAAX';
```

[image: Query Result 1]

Now, I want to group these, keeping the value from the row with the most recent created date. I've tried all the various solutions I've seen online:

1) the subquery where we first query and order by, then we have an outer query group. It doesn't work:

```
select cm.CreatedDate, cm.Id, cm.CampaignId, cm.ContactId 
From (select * from campaignmember as cm  where ContactId = '0035000002MYN7IAAX' order by cm.CreatedDate desc) as cm 
group by cm.ContactId;
```

[image: Query Result 2]

2) Using Max() function. As we would expect, we get the max date alright, but not the associated row:

```
select max(cm.CreatedDate), cm.Id, cm.CampaignId, cm.ContactId 
From  campaignmember as cm 
where cm.ContactId = '0035000002MYN7IAAX';
```

[image: Query Result 3]

3) The last suggestion I could see how it would work, but here we go:

```
select max(cm.CreatedDate), cm.Id, cm.CampaignId, cm.ContactId 
From  campaignmember as cm 
where cm.ContactId =  '0035000002MYN7IAAX'group by cm.ContactId 
order by max(cm.CreatedDate) desc;
```

[image: Query Result 4]

this is driving me insane (always has). I wouldn't think it would be this difficult... Any suggestion would be really, really appreciated!

Comment: avoid grouping by part only of selected fields. This is a powerful late addition to sql standards that one should not abuse of. I've been creating advance queries since 10 years and the real need for it happened to me once only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select cm.CreatedDate, cm.Id, cm.CampaignId, cm.ContactId 
from campaignmember as cm where cm.ContactId = '0035000002MYN7IAAX'
and cm.CreatedDate = (select max(c.CreatedDate) from campaignmember c 
                      where c.ContactId = cm.ContactId);
```

Hope help you =)